# Generic pattern matching in function argument

Tags: f#

Let say I have DU of three types and a function which accepts this DU as a parameter:

```
    type A = decimal<p>
    type B = decimal<p>
    type C = decimal<p>

    type ABC = A of A | B of B | C of C

    let myfunc (val: ABC) = 
        match val with
        | A v -> ...
        | B v -> ...
        | C v -> ...
```

Is there a better way to define a function which accepts DU of only A and B without defining new type explicity?

This is a working example:

```
    type AB = A2 of A | B2 of B 

    let myfunc2 (val: AB) = 
        match val with
        | A2 v -> ...
        | B2 v -> ...
```

This is how I would like it to be:

```
    let myfunc2 (val: A|B) = 
        match val with
        | A v -> ...
        | B v -> ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language feature you're asking for is open variants, which exists in OCaml, but not in F#. For instance,

```
type ABC = A of int | B of int | C of int
type AB  = A of int | B of int 

let myfunc (x: AB) = ...
```

is legal in OCaml. This can also be achieved with type-erased DUs ([vote for it here!](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/538)).

DU cases in F# are not actual types, but the base type (`ABC`) with a tag denoting which union case it is. And since there are no types which exist separately, it follows that they cannot be used as a type constraint.

---

You can however try and work around this with `Choice`. The idea is to build single case DUs and then combine them with `Choice<T1, T2...>`.

```
type A = A of int
type B = B of int
type C = C of int

type ABC = Choice<A, B, C>
type AB  = Choice<A, B>

let matchAb (x: AB) =
    match x with
    | Choice1Of2 (A a) -> a
    | Choice2Of2 (B b) -> b
```